# Must "private readonly int" be thread safe when used in multi-thread App?

Tags: c#, multithreading, readonly

In my multi-threaded App I have a class containing a `private readonly` instance variable that is initialized in the constructor by a random number.

```
class MyClass
{
  private readonly int randomNumber;


  public MyClass()
  {
    randomNumber = new Random().Next();
  }

  // Is called by different threads
  public int getRandomNumber()
  {
   return randomNumber;
  }
}
```

In the app `getRandomNumber()` is called by multiple threads. Must I undertake any precautions regarding thread safety?

As a follow-up question: What does change regarding my threat-safety concerns when I make the variable static and initialize it at declaration like this?

```
class MyClass
{
  private static readonly int randomNumber = new Random().Next();

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precautions are required only in case of read and write both, but as your variable is read-only, I think there is no need of any precautions in any case wether it is Multithreading or single threading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - no other code can see the object before it's entirely constructed.

**Note:**

1. We need to take care in case we perform constructor chaining.
2. Also,  it depends on the type, for example for a dictionary as read-only we are allowed to perform certain key-value operations

Comment: In my case however there is no constructor chaining and the type is int. So, do I still have to take any measures for thread safety? My guess is as Anoop Mourya said, that I do not have to do anything because it is read only and is only consumed within the class, since it is private.

Comment: @reto being consumed within the class does not make any variable thread safe.  Just saying for future readers the **only reason** it might be thread safe is due to it being read-only (unless threads are created in the constructor).

Comment: @Reto your code looks good to go. I just mentioned the cases where we need to be careful with readonly.